# find probability of taking taxi between two places

Tags: probability

Tom knows that the bus will arrive at station at random between 7:00 am to 8:30 am. He will go at random to the station to get a bus to work and waits for 5 minutes, if he misses the bus, he will take taxi to work.
what is the probability that tom takes taxi to work? (assume uniform distribution for bus arrival and tom arrival to the station)

Comment: How frequently do the taxis come?

Comment: @Rohan I think it is assumed that there are always some taxis at the (bus-, taxi-, subway-, railway-) station. The taxi drivers are just waiting for costumers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the visualization below. The $x$-axis represents the time Tom arrives at the station after 7:00 am. Similarly, the $y$-axis represents the time the bus arrives at the station after 7:00 am. The event ends at 8:30 am, 90 minutes after 7:00 am.

[image: Visualization]

The entire area describes all possible event because each point on the plane describes the time the bus arrives at the station and the time Tom arrives at the station respectively. Notice the black strip. That's when Tom is able to catch the bus because that is when the bus arrives within 5 minutes after Tom's arrival. Hence the probability of Tom taking the taxi is

$\frac{\text{white area}}{\text{area of the square}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\times 90\times 90 + \frac{1}{2}\times 85\times 85}{90\times 90} = \frac{613}{648}$.

Answer (score 0):

I like the graphical approach, but I will add a more conventional probability theoretic argument.

Consider the joint probability of Tom's arrival, $f_T(t) = \frac{1}{90}$, and of the bus's arrival, $f_B(b)= \frac{1}{90}$: $f_{T,B} = \frac{1}{90^2}$. Here we are assuming that the arrivals are independent with supports $(0, 90)$, i.e. the minutes after 7:00 a.m. of arrival. We are interested in the probability of the random variable $Z = T - B$ being between $0$ and $5$. The density of $Z$ is $f_Z(z) = \int_0^{90}f_T(t)f_B(t-z)dt$; this is the probability of the Tom arriving at a given time $t$ and then the bus arriving within $z$ minutes, added over all of the times that Tom could arrive.

The support of this distribution depends on $z$. We need $0  < t - z < 90$, or $z<t<z+90$. When $z \in (0,90)$, we have $t \in (z, 90)$. So the distribution's density for these points is $f_Z(z) = \int_{z}^{90}\frac{1}{90^2}dt = \frac{90-z}{90^2}$. Integrating over $(0, 5)$, we get that the probability of $Z$ falling in this interval as $\frac{35}{648}$ (after a bit of integration). Then, it follows that the probability of $Z$ falling outside this range and hence Tom taking the taxi is $\frac{613}{648}$.